# Error when verifying deployed factory smart contract on explorer with remix

Tags: blockchain, factory, smartcontracts, uniswap, pancakeswap

I deployed the smart contract on the blockchain with remix ide, when i want to verify it on the blockchain explorer it throws this error "Bytecode does not match, please try again."

I am trying to verify the standard pancakeswap factory contract

https://bscscan.com/address/0xBCfCcbde45cE874adCB698cC183deBcF17952812#code

pragma solidity =0.5.16;

I forked the code and deployed it and don't know how to fix the error.

Comment: are you sure you accidentally didn't make any changes to it? after deploying?

Comment: Yes, nothing is modified.

Comment: I am trying to verify the contract on dogechain explorer, i've teste the same contract on other blockchains and everything went ok.